# Show In/Out names in some notebooks but not others?

Tags: notebooks

I often have a working notebook and a "publication notebook". Figures and results are copied to the publication notebook to which explanatory text is added. The publication notebook can then be saved as PDF to provide a good read for others.

I don't want the In/Out tags in the publication notebook so I go to preferences >> evaluation and untick the box with In/Out names. This, of course, removes In/Out tags from all notebooks. I don't want this I just want them absent from the publication notebook.

Is it possible to set some option so that one notebook does not show In/Out tags but others do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute the following inside the notebook

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellLabel -> False]
```

Alternatively, you can change the options of the desired notebook (`testnb1.nb` in the example below) by executing  `SetOptions[...]` in a different notebook (`untitled-3.nb` in the example):
[image]

Or, use the `Option Inspector` (in the Format Menu) to change `ShowCellLabel` in `Cell Options >> Evaluation Options >> Cell Labels`  to `False`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many thanks. Now frequently in use.

Comment: @Hugh, glad i was able to help. Thank you for the accept.